# Android: recalculate dimension of layout components

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, dimensions, invalidation

I've a linear layout with few compononents, most of them have setted specific dimensions, but 1 is set to `0dp` in other to fill the remaining space.

The thing is after inflate the xml layout i programatically add one more component, and the `0dp` view doesn't shrink to fit this new component so it makes the layout to appear wrongly.

There are enough space for all components, if i try for example to add the "dinamic" component on the xml (just for test) and inflate it, all will appear well.

How can i force a `LinearLayout` to re-calculate the views height?

what i get:
[image]
here goes the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/smallMargin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/smallMargin"
        android:visibility="visible">

               <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/giveawayResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/giveawayCardHeight"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/giveawayCardHeight">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/raffleThumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/asd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/raffleOwner"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:alpha="0.7"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:text="viajandocomgabi"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/smallMargin"

                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/raffleDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"

                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/raffle_date_label"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/discreteFont" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/amountToIndicate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"

                    android:hint="@string/prompt_friends_to_indicate"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/discreteFont" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/save" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

=========UPDATE==========

To make things clear:
1- the adview is added dynamically
2- the recycleview is `0dp` because i want it to fill the left space

3- after inflating the layout the recycleview is dimentioned by android api, after that i add the adview, and IT DOESN'T GET RESIZED, so the result is what you see on the photo

i need to know how to force android to redimensionate recycleview to shrink to fit the space

Comment: Something doesn't look right, other than the obvious, your banner should not be able to go over the top of another view in a `LinearLayout` - maybe it would help if you added the code where you inflate the layout, and which `ViewGroup` it is inflated into. Currently looks more like it is inflated into a `CoordinateLayout` or `FrameLayout`

Comment: I found the problem... there was a wrong calculation on the margins of this Adview what made it got negative margins and all the related mess

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the LinearLayout, or any view, you use its `invalidate()` method.

Edit: If you wish to remeasure the view, call it's `requestLayout()` method. Don't forget to invalidate it too.

Also, your Admob Banner Ad is breaking their Policy. Banner Ads can't overlap on app content.

Comment: you probably didn't read carefully what i wrote. the banner is that way because of the layout problem, second invalidate doens't solve it

Comment: invalidate doesn't work as 99% people just think... it is not the silver bullet method for layout problems...

Comment: @RafaelLima Actually, I've read carefully enough. No where does it say that your Admob Banner is like that because of the layout problem. It's actually like that because you didn't provide it a dedicated space that is separate from your app content. If you did, layout problems won't be able to reach that area.

Comment: @RafaelLima, your question was "How can i force a LinearLayout to re-calculate the views height?" and Jackey answered "invalidate()" which is a correct answer but again it might not help you due to your close case. Either you need to learn how to ask a question properly or you need to learn when to downvote. Good luck!

Comment: it doesnt work also... you guys are just "guessing" the answer and all of this were things i tried before asking because it is the "obvious ideas"... but it looks to me that android api doesn't recalculate size of its `0dp` views, only the `wrap_content` and `match_parent`...

Comment: @RafaelLima To be honest, I am just tossing out the most obvious, since the screenshot baffles me. LinearLayout layouts all views sequentially and it doesn't allow for overlapping which made me originally believe the view you're programmatically adding wasn't the AdView. The overlap made it appear as if the AdView is in a separate container, which if it is... then invalidating and requesting layout for any of the views you show won't work. I really do want to help, but from the code you showed and screenshot, I can't help but feel there's info missing, so I can only toss out the obvious.

Comment: "all of this were things i tried before asking" - are we mind readers?????? Maybe add "Things I've tried"? Your defensiveness is not helping.  @Jackey - I already mentioned the overlapping in a direct comment, with a decent suggestion to improve the quality of the question .. however the OP prefers to spend time being defensive in comments ..